# How can I save my data source of Tableau into Excel

Tags: export-to-excel, tableau-api

I loaded a .txt file into tableau server, and I tried to turn it into excel. I tried the crosstab to excel, but it only allowed my current sheet to be saved as excel. Is there anyway that I can save the metadata of tableau read from .txt into excel? Normal way will save the data into .twbx or .tde but not .xlsx.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Oh... ok, but I was wondering if I can use tableau to do some editing to the  data and save it to excel for other application analysis. Because the document was too large and in .txt it was convenient to use tableau to read and clean. But thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out a possible way to solve this problem. Put measure names to columns and measure values to rows. Right click the sheet to view data, click full data, and click export.

Answer (score 1):

You **can** do this, by the way. If you are able to create a sheet/view of your data, you can Export that data:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I was working on saving the metadata. But maybe there is was to show all metadata on a sheet though.

Comment: By metadata you mean the field data types? If so, Excel has data types and export should retain them. If you mean something else, please clarify.

Comment: I mean the source data, the original data without any editing.